# virtual dmg image keeps reloading and never goes away even after ejecting on OS X

Tags: macos, mac, finder, dmg-image, eject

I am on OS X 10.11.5
I've downloaded a demo software which came in a DMG file. I double clicked the DMG file and as expected it showed up on the desktop and in the Finder's side bar as a drive would.
I then ejected this image as I would with an external drive. It goes away and then after a minute or so it comes back and re-mounts without me doing anything.
I've ejected in dozens of time and have restarted the computer. I also looked into my user's Login Item and it's not there either...
How do I get rid of it?
Thanks

Comment: Try deleting the underlying DMG file or renaming it and/or changing it's folder location. If it continues to mount after all of that, I would scan for a virus, to be safe

Comment: It's most likely that something has an alias to the disk image or something on it, and is periodically accessing it (and therefore triggering it to mount). What files on the image did you use and how did you use them?